# wxExecuted process is not deleted when main window exits

Tags: asynchronous, process, wxwidgets, child-process, wxlua

I am using wxLua with wxWidgets 2.8.12 for Windows. In the following code, I try to asynchronously execute some command and redirect its output.

The problem is, if I close main window before child process terminates, the child process is not deleted. I could still see "tree.com" process inside Windows Task Manager after this wxLua app exits.

What is the problem with my code below?

---

```lua
require("wx")

frame = wx.wxFrame(wx.NULL, wx.wxID_ANY, "Test")

function ExecCommand(cmd)
   proc = wx.wxProcess(frame)
   proc:Redirect()
   pid = wx.wxExecute(cmd, wx.wxEXEC_ASYNC, proc)
   if pid > 0 then
       print("process id is " .. tostring(pid))
       streamIn = proc and proc:GetInputStream()
   end
end

function ReadStream()
   if streamIn and streamIn:CanRead() then
       local str = streamIn:Read(4096)
   end
end

frame:Connect(wx.wxEVT_IDLE, ReadStream)

frame:Connect(wx.wxEVT_END_PROCESS, function(event)
   proc = nil
end)

frame:Connect(wx.wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, function(event)
   if proc then proc:Detach() end
   event:Skip()
end)

frame:Show(true)

cmd = "tree.com C:\\Windows"

ExecCommand(cmd)

wx.wxGetApp():MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't kill the child process, so it continues running, why shouldn't it? If you don't want this to happen, you need to `Kill()` it explicitly using its PID.

BTW, please also update to wxWidgets 3.0, especially as you're using Lua, there shouldn't be any compatibility concerns, but you would be using a supported version with a lot of new features and bug fixes compared to the 10+ year old 2.8.

Comment: But the executed cmd would exit automatically if it finished running before I close main window. In this case I could not see "tree.com" process inside Windows Task Manager. Why this difference occurs?

Comment: [wxWidgets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_process.html#a19cdb21f39fd9f758c7e3661426bcf9f) says: However, it might happen that the parent object is destroyed before the external process is terminated (e.g. a window from which this external process was launched is closed by the user) and in this case it should **not** delete the wxProcess object, but should call Detach() instead.

Comment: There is a difference between `wxProcess` C++ object and the external process, identified by its PID. You seem to be confusing the two.

Comment: Normally, The cmd will exit by itself so we need not to kill it. I could not understand, in wxwidgets, what stops it from exiting if we close main windows soon?

Comment: It might be blocking on its end of the redirected pipe, although this is indeed surprising, I think it should get an error writing to the closed pipe. I understood your initial post about asking why doesn't the child process exit immediately, if it doesn't exit *at all*, then it's different and I'm afraid I don't really know what's going on.